# Apply scroll to specific DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a transparent div that overlays the table in the picture.

This is because, without the div I would not be able to place the blue bars outside of the table.

But now the table does not scroll anymore.

Is it possible to apply the scroll only to the table?

[image: original style problem]

Comment: It should be possible to add CSS `overflow: scroll` to any element on the page with `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Try adding overflow:scroll

Comment: requirement not clear. please add code or pictorial representation of your requirement.

Comment: `overflow:auto` for blue div will make it scroll if you set a fixed height to it and the content of the blue div exceeds the height limit...

Comment: Move the card outside table.... If the card is positioned fixed, you don't need any parent to it. It should be direct child of `body`.... Still, share your code for better understanding. I am just guessing.

Comment: Have you added the CSS `pointer-events: none;` to the transparent card?

Comment: @RouninsaysJesuisMonica perfect, I added pointer-events:none to the transparent div and pointer-events:visible to the bars and now it works. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `pointer-events:none` to the transparent `div` and `pointer-events:visible` to the bars and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

you need to have an HTML document and a CSS document first. then you want to add create an ID within your Div and set it equal to something like `<div id = "scrolling"></div>`

then you want to create a CSS document call this index.CSS. Call your id in the CSS and add the parameter `overflow: scroll` it should look like this

HTML documemnt.

```
<div id = "scrolling">
<p> this is your text </p>
</div>
```

CSS document

```
#scrolling {
overflow: scroll;
}
```